# MySQL Deadlock Issue

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am working on online trading project. 
I insert one row on table t1 (innoDB engine) and there is one trigger on after insert event.  
In trigger, i fetch data using select statement in same table like "**SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID**".  
It works perfectly 2-3 months. but now it gives Deadlock issue.  
what is reason behind it ?  
is it possible while multiple thread access same operation on same table at a time ?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
SQL [ INSERT INTO t1( ID, NAME, ADDRESS )  VALUES( ?,?,?)]; 
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:300)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want the id that you have inserted before ?

you can try something like this

```
INSERT INTO table1 (title,userid) VALUES ('test', 1); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: If I put New.ID in trigger then it work perfactly. but i fetch using select query like "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ID = NEW.ID" then its give me deadlock issue what is reason behind it ? and why its work perfectly 3 month and suddenly give deadlock error ?

Comment: i dont know exactly, but might be you have not build your function thread safe, so this is being called simultaneously.

pl. try making the db function / java code thread safe